# Laravel keyBy - Sorting results from linked table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a BlogPost model that has a belongsToMany relationship called images, this relationship uses a link table to associate the blog post id with the image id.

When pulling in the data for a blog post, the images property looks like this:

```
[images] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 8304
                        [original] => /img/blog/2017/5/wifiradio_original_59089cae673db.png
                        [large] => /img/blog/2017/5/wifiradio_large_59089cae673db.jpg
                        [medium] => /img/blog/2017/5/wifiradio_medium_59089cae673db.jpg
                        [small] => /img/blog/2017/5/wifiradio_small_59089cae673db.jpg
                        [name] => wifiradio.png
                        [alt] => wifiradio.png
                        [created_at] => 2017-05-02 14:50:22
                        [updated_at] => 2017-05-02 14:50:22
                        [pivot] => Array
                            (
                                [blog_post_id] => 47749
                                [image_id] => 8304
                                [id] => 136949
                                [type] => featured
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

The array key is not useful as the numeric value, i would like the array key to be the value of pivot->type.

Laravels keyBy method almost does what I need but I can not get it to work directly on the data returned.

Is it possible to use keyBy from within the model so that data is always returned in a useable format?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by formatting the array within the controller. 
Here's the function I created if anyone has a similair problem:

```
public function formatPosts($posts){
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $images = collect($post->images);
        unset($post->images);
        $post->images = $images->keyBy('pivot.type');
    }
    return $posts;
}
```